# How to draw multiple bitmap using paint?

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to draw multiple bitmap using this code.

```
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      Path path = new Path(); // path of crop
      for (int i = 0; i < Crop.points.size(); i++) {
          path.lineTo(Crop.points.get(i).x, Crop.points.get(i).y);

canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

bitmap1=  highlightImage(bitmap1); //bitmap1 drawn completely
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));// select inside part of crop
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);// draw crop part
```

highlightImage is a method for blurring a bitmap. This canvas first draw bitmap1 that is blurred and then draw bitmap2.

The problem is, when I use only this code:

```
bitmap1=  highlightImage(bitmap1);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, paint);
```

the bitmap1 is blurred and drawn correctly, but when I use this

```
bitmap1=  highlightImage(bitmap1);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
```

the bitmap1 is drawn but without the blur effect. What's the problem?
the first image is the image of blur bitmap
the second one is for the time that two bit map is drawn. you can see that is transparent without blur effect.

```
[first ][1]
[second ][2]
[what I want][3]
```

Comment: post some images with your results

Comment: first of all, what is `bitmap2` used for? for a mask or something? if so, what shape is it? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have an app that crop a picture and blur the outside part. so the inside part is not blurred. using above code, the bitmap1 is blured and then drawn in canvas. bitmap1 and bitmap2 are same. so bitmap1 is drawn completely. then bitmap2 is drawn. bitmap2 is drawn according to the path of crop.

Comment: @pskink I edited the question

Comment: @pskink can you help me?

Comment: `"bitmap1 and bitmap2 are same"` so why do you want to draw them both? what is the reason? i still don't know what you want to achieve... maybe some image describing what you wanna do?

Comment: I want to blur a part of bitmap. so first I crop bitmap and then I want to blur outside section of bitmap. I will add picture

Comment: If you want I can send whole project to see what I mean